# Find index of maximum value from each row in a multidimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to find the index of the maximum value from each array. For example: `[[1,2,3,4],[5,10,2,3]]` should return `[3,1]`.

Current code:

```py
import numpy as np

def display_max(input_array):
    b = np.max(input_array)
    c = np.where(input_array==b)
    return c

display_max([[[7,15,3,10],[2,6,9,0],[20,45,71,500]]])
```

Current output:

```py
(array([0], dtype=int64), array([2], dtype=int64), array([3], dtype=int64))
```

I'm confused why the first array didn't return the correct value, 1. But I want a simple output like the example above.

Comment: If this question is answered by one of the submitted answers then you should accept that answer. Otherwise, update your question to clarify your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have two solutions for you.
Number 1: your input is a numpy array

```
import numpy as np    
np.argmax(np.array([[7,15,3,10],[2,6,9,0],[20,45,71,500]]), axis=1)
```

Number 2: your input is (as in the original question) a list of lists. You can solve this without numpy

```
def display_max_list_of_lists(input_list):
    """find the indicees of the maximum values of lists of lists"""
    res = []
    # loop over list of lists
    for l in input_list:
        # find index of max using a list comprehension
        i0 = [i for i in range(len(l)) if l[i]==max(l)][0]
        res.append(i0)

    return res

print(display_max_list_of_lists([[7,15,3,10],[2,6,9,0],[20,45,71,500]]))
```

Be aware, that your input list of lists had one excess bracket...

Comment: Both works, thanks ! But how to simplify the output into 1,2,3 instead of (current output : array([1, 2, 3], dtype=int64)

Comment: `list(np.argmax(np.array([[7,15,3,10],[2,6,9,0],[20,45,71,500]]), axis=1))`

Comment: For large arrays, I believe the `tolist()` method is faster, i.e. `np.array([1,2,3]).tolist()`.

Comment: @AmeliaPutriDamayanti One question, tho, is "why would you want to get rid of the `array` part?". Because it seems that your motivation (from the start, since that was also why you weren't happy with your own solution), is just a display consideration. Here you said "simplify". When it is not really a simplification. It is just a matter of typing. For many operation, this one included, it is handling list rather than ndarray that induces unnecessay complexity

Comment: @AmeliaPutriDamayanti (this is why RC had to convert the list with `np.array`. He could have skipped this ; `np.argmax([[7,15,3,10],[2,6,9,0],[20,45,71,500]], axis=1)` would have given the same result. But it is slower.). So it is not a simplification. Just a simpler display that you want. And the display you see here is not even a proper one: it is just the display of the interactive shell.

Comment: @AmeliaPutriDamayanti. So, rather than using slow computation to keep the type as lists; or using unnecessary complex type conversion to have the return value display without the "array" part in the interactive shell, you should use the optimal type for the task. Which, here, at least with this solution, but I don't think you could find a better solution than this answer, is numpy array. And then, if needed, use a display function when displaying, to match your desire. No need to look very far here: `print` displays arrays as you want already.

Comment: In short: `print(np.argmax(np.array([[7,15,3,10],[2,6,9,0],[20,45,71,500]]), axis=1))` seems to be what you really want. Rather than `list(p.argmax(np.array([[7,15,3,10],[2,6,9,0],[20,45,71,500]]), axis=1))` that does an unnecessary conversion to a here useless type, just for the sake of its default appearance in the interactive python REPL.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without any libraries by making use of the built-in `max` function and the array `index` method. For each of the arrays, we can find the max value using `max` and then find the index of that value (if the number appears more than once it will return the index of the first appearance) using the `index` method.

```py
def display_max(input_array):
    return [row.index(max(row)) for row in input_array[0]]

res = display_max([[[7,15,3,10],[2,6,9,0],[20,45,71,500]]])
print(res)
```

This outputs:

```py
[1, 2, 3]
```

Note: I indexed the zeroth element of `input_array` because you have two levels of parenthesis before the inner arrays. I don't know if that was intentional or a typo, so I left it in case it was intentional. If your input array doesn't have that extra level, for example, `input_array = [[7,15,3,10],[2,6,9,0],[20,45,71,500]]`, then you can remove the 0 indexing in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the list to a numpy array, something like this if you want to stick with a function doing the job

```
import numpy as np

def display_max(input_array):
    max_indices = np.argmax(np.array(input_array), axis=1)
    return max_indices

max_indices = display_max([[[7,15,3,10],[2,6,9,0],[20,45,71,500]]])
print(max_indices)
```

Answer (score -1):

Below code will find biggest number in the 3-dimensional array instead of max number in each row:

```
np.max(input_array)
```

As biggest number is 500, in the 3-dimensional array, its index is [0,2,3], that's why it returns 0 as first dimension